# How to XOR hex values in a list with another fixed hex value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, xor

I have a list containing hex values, e.g.:

```
initial_list = ['C2', 'DA', 'DA', 'C6', 'D6']
```

and I want to XOR each value with another fixed hex value and put the result in a new list, for example with `0xBA` the result would be:

```
result_list = ['78', '60', '60', '7C', '6C']
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
initial_list=['C2', 'DA', 'DA', 'C6', 'D6']
print ['{:02X}'.format( int(i, 16) ^ 0xBA)  for i in initial_list]
```

For python3, try:

```
print(list(['{:02X}'.format( int(i, 16) ^ 0xBA)  for i in initial_list]))
```

Output:

```
['78', '60', '60', '7C', '6C']
```

Comment: `format(thing, '02X')` is neater than slicing, and lets you control capitalisation.